# Levy process and random measure

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, pricing, jump-diffusion

I am wondering if random measures are used under a Levy process and how this connects to finance (particularly pricing). Any paper or books for suggestions is welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

There is a whole literature on risk-neutral modeling with Levy processes.

---

Consider an arbitrage-free market where asset prices are modeled by a stochastic process $(S_t)_{t \in [0,T]}, \mathcal{F}_t$ represents the history of the asset $S$ and $\hat{S}_t=e^{-rt}S_T$ the stochastic discounted value of the asset. The discounted expectation of the terminal payoffs under $Q$ is

$$\hat{S}_t = \operatorname{E}^{Q}[\hat{S}_T|\mathcal{F}_t]$$

There are two ways to define the risk neutral dynamics in the Black-Scholes model using a Brownian motion with drift:

1. Taking the exponential, i.e. $S_t=S_0 e^{B_t^0}$, where $B_t^0=(r-\sigma^2/2)t + \sigma W_t$, which is a brownian motion with drift.
2. Taking the stochastic exponential by applying Ito formula, i.e. $\frac{dS_t}{S_t}=rdt + \sigma dW_t=dB_t^1$, where $B_t^1=rt+\sigma W_t$.

Levy-processes are often used for modeling jump-processes (see [Cox/Ross(1976)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-405X(76)90023-4) or [Merton(1976)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-405X(76)90022-2)), especially in [jump-diffusion models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_affine_jump_diffusion).

In the formulas above, we can generalize the Black-Scholes model to account for jumps, by replacing the brownian motion with drift by a Levy-process. Therefore, we get

1. $S_t = S_0 e^{rt + X_t}$, which is an exponential-Levy model as $(X_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ describes a Levy-process.
2. Replace $B_t^1$ by a Levy-process $Z_t$ results in $dS_t=rS_tdt + S_tdZ_t$.

Furthermore, exponential-Levy models offer analytically tractable examples of positive jump processes. The availability of closed-form expressions for characteristic function of Levy processes also allows to use Fourier transform methods for option pricing.

I recommend the following literature on Levy-processes and their use in finance:

- Measure transformations for Levy-processes are discussed in [Sato(1999)](https://doi.org/10.2307/3621820)
- More general martingale measures for processes with independent increments are discussed in [Grandits(1999)](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0040585X97977355).
- The absence of arbitrage and completeness for models with jumps is discussed in [Bardhan(1999)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3690118).
- Predictable representations for Levy processes in terms of a sequence of jump martingales were introduced by [Nualart/Schoutens(2000)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-4149(00)00035-1) and [Nualart/Schoutens(2001)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3318541). A financial interpretation of their results in terms of hedging with vanilla options is given by [Balland(2002)](https://doi.org/10.1088/1469-7688/2/1/303).

**Reference:**

Cont/Tankov (2004), *Financial Modelling With Jump Processes*, Chapman & Hall/CRC Financial Mathematics Series